# Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'and'

Tags: mysql, procedure

When i run the following code in mysql workbench im getting the above mentioned error Pls do help

```
#   IF p_Name is not null THEN
 #                   SET m_sql = m_sql +' Name=''' + p_Name + ''' and ';
#   END IF;


     If p_ReligionID is not null THEN
                    SET m_sql = m_sql + '" ReligionId= "' + 'CAST(p_ReligionID AS CHAR(30))' + 'and';
    END IF;

     If p_CasteID is not null THEN
                    SET m_sql = m_sql + '" CasteId= "' + 'CAST(p_CasteID AS CHAR(30))'  + 'and';

    END IF;

    If p_CountryID is not null THEN
                    SET m_sql=m_sql+    '"  Countryid= "' + 'CAST(p_CountryID AS CHAR(30))' + 'and';
    END IF;

    If p_MotherTongueID is not null THEN
                    SET m_sql=m_sql+'"  MotherTongueID= "' + 'CAST(p_MotherTongueID AS CHAR(30))' + 'and';
    END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming m_sql is valid on entry and at least one of the conditions passes, the final statement ends with an 'and'. That's not valid SQL in any dialect I know. Then you have to deal with what appears to be extraneous quoting.

I'd suggest the ANDs be inserted at the beginning of the follow-on condition

```
 If p_ReligionID is not null THEN
                SET m_sql = m_sql + ' and ReligionId = ' + 'CAST(p_ReligionID AS CHAR(30))';
END IF;
```

(I'm a SQL Server person, so the particulars of MySql's procedural language are beyond my ken)